How can I style a table with a header to have all columns but one fit their content, with the final column taking up all remaining space?
I want all of the columns in my table to have a width that matches their content, no more, no less. I want that width the stay the same as the screen resizes. I want one column in my table to grow to fill the remaining space. Its width should change as the window re-sizes.
My problem is that with multiple rows and a table header, I don't know how to achieve this. I can make it work by hard coding the column widths for the columns that I want to remain static, but I don't want that -- I want their widths to be determined by the content.
This is working (based on another stack overflow response), but does not adapt to the content in columns 1 and 2


table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.small {
  background: green;
  width: 80px;
}

.extend {
  background: red;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="small">Column 1</th>
    <th class="extend">Column 2</th>
    <th class="small">Column 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="small">First column</td>
      <td class="extend">This column should fill the remaining space </td>
      <td class="small">Small column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Here is my fiddle.

Looks like I can achieve this by using table-layout: auto and setting width: 100% on the cells of the column I would like to expand
fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/klister/ks1u7zf6/54/


table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: auto
}

.small {
  background: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.extend {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="small">Column 1</th>
      <th class="extend">Column 2</th>
      <th class="small">Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="small">First column more content</td>
      <td class="extend">expandable </td>
      <td class="small">Small</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Leverage fit-content and white-space: nowrap?


table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.small {
  background: green;
  width: fit-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.extend {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="small">Column 1</th>
    <th class="extend">Column 2</th>
    <th class="small">Column 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="small">First column</td>
      <td class="extend">This column should fill the remaining space </td>
      <td class="small">Small column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




I just ran this code snippet, and it doesn't solve my problem. You'll notice that if you reduce the text in column 2, columns 1 and 3 still grow to fill available space. Instead, they should remain a static width based only on their own content

Then just make the red section 100%... see updated demo.

thanks! just figured that out in my fiddle :)

table {  
    display: inline-table; 
    width: 99.5%; 
    table-layout: auto; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 40 !important; 
}

.small { 
    background: green; 
    width: 104px;
    text-align: center; 
}

.extend { 
    background: red; 
    text-align: center; 
}


I think that will work for ya.
but I will suggest that ,yeah, even if it will take a massive amount of time to write I think you should write h1 inside th or td if you will work in bigger projects in the future. Bc it is easier to make changes to them rather than trying to find the good and brief explanation to this. It will just be easier you know but yeah I think what I wrote above should work

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
